# Jquery copy all text field and drop down values for shipping over to billing when checkbox clicked

Tags: jquery, forms, selectlist

I have some code for this already, and it works 90% correctly. I just can't get it to carry over the drop down values.

Essentially, when the checkbox is clicked I simply need it to carry over all of the listed billing fields over to shipping. All of the text content work correctly, but the drop downs do nothing. I'm this is a simple oversight on my part..

Here it is:

```
 //copy billing information over to shipping information fields
 $(function(){
     $("#shipping_same_as_billing").change(function() {
         if ($("#shipping_same_as_billing:checked").length > 0) {
             bindGroups();
         } else {
             unbindGroups();
         }
     });
 });

 var bindGroups = function() {
     // First copy values
     $("input[name='shipping_name']").val($("input[name='billing_name']").val());
     $("input[name='shipping_address1']").val($("input[name='billing_address1']").val());
     $("input[name='shipping_address2']").val($("input[name='billing_address2']").val());
     $("input[name='shipping_city']").val($("input[name='billing_city']").val());
     $("input[name='shipping_postcode']").val($("input[name='billing_postcode']").val());
     $("input[name='shipping_state']").val($("input[name='billing_state']").val());
     $("input[name='shipping_country']").val($("input[name='billing_country']").val());
     $("input[name='shipping_phone']").val($("input[name='billing_phone']").val());            

     // Then bind fields
     $("input[name='billing_name']").keyup(function() {
         $("input[name='shipping_name']").val($(this).val());
     });
     $("input[name='billing_address1']").keyup(function() {
         $("input[name='shipping_address']").val($(this).val());
     });
     $("input[name='billing_address2']").keyup(function() {
         $("input[name='shipping_address2']").val($(this).val());
     });
     $("input[name='billing_city']").keyup(function() {
         $("input[name='shipping_city']").val($(this).val());
     });
     $("input[name='billing_postcode']").keyup(function() {
         $("input[name='shipping_postcode']").val($(this).val());
     });
     $("input[name='billing_state']").keyup(function() {
         $("input[name='shipping_state']").val($(this).val());
     });
     $("input[name='billing_country']").keyup(function() {
         $("input[name='shipping_country']").val($(this).val());
     });
     $("input[name='billing_phone']").keyup(function() {
         $("input[name='shipping_phone']").val($(this).val());
     });            
 };

 var unbindGroups = function() {
     $("input[name='billing_name']").unbind("keyup");
     $("input[name='billing_address1']").unbind("keyup");
     $("input[name='billing_address2']").unbind("keyup");
     $("input[name='billing_city']").unbind("keyup");
     $("input[name='billing_postcode']").unbind("keyup");
     $("input[name='billing_state']").unbind("keyup");
     $("input[name='billing_country']").unbind("keyup");
     $("input[name='billing_phone']").unbind("keyup");
 };
```

As requested, here is the full HTML code. Please be aware, there's some CMS\Code Igniter specific code here.

```
<div class="w-row">
  <div class="w-col w-col-6 checkoutcolumn1">
    <div class="forminfotextblock">
      <p class="forminfotext">Contact Details</p>
    </div>
    <div class="formblock">
      <div class="w-form">
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            {error:billing_name}<label class="checkoutlabel" for="name">Name:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="billing_name" type="text" name="billing_name" value="{billing_name}">                   
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            {error:billing_address1}<label class="checkoutlabel" for="name-3">Address:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="billing_address1" type="text" name="billing_address1" value="{billing_address1}">
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            <label class="checkoutlabel" for="name-4">Address 2:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="billing_address2" type="text" name="billing_address2" value="{billing_address2}">
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            {error:billing_city}<label class="checkoutlabel" for="name-5">City:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="billing_city" type="text" name="billing_city" value="{billing_city}">
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            <label class="checkoutlabel" for="name-6">Postcode:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="billing_postcode" type="text" name="billing_postcode" value="{billing_postcode}">
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            <label class="checkoutlabel" for="billing_state">State:</label>
            <select class="w-select checkoutfield" id="billing_state" name="billing_state" value="{billing_state}">
              {billing_state_options}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
           {error:billing_country}<label class="checkoutlabel" for="billing_country">Country:</label>
            <select class="w-select checkoutfield" id="billing_country" name="billing_country" value="{billing_country}">
              {billing_country_options}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            {error:order_email}<label class="checkoutlabel" for="name-9">Email:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="order_email" type="text" name="order_email" value="{order_email}">
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            <label class="checkoutlabel" for="name-10">Phone:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="billing_phone" type="text" name="billing_phone" value="{billing_phone}">
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            <label class="checkoutlabel" for="name-11">Instructions:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="order_custom1" type="text" name="order_custom1" value="{order_custom1}">
          </div>
          <div class="w-checkbox">
            <input type="hidden" name="shipping_same_as_billing" value="0" />
            <input class="w-checkbox-input" id="shipping_same_as_billing" type="checkbox" name="shipping_same_as_billing" value="1" {shipping_same_as_billing_checked}>
            <label class="w-form-label" for="shipping_same_as_billing">Same details for shipping</label>               
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-6 checkoutcolumn2">
    <div class="forminfotextblock">
      <p class="forminfotext">Shipping Address</p>
    </div>
    <div class="formblock">
      <div class="w-form">
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            {error:shipping_name}<label class="checkoutlabel" for="name-14">Name:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="shipping_name" type="text" name="shipping_name" value="{shipping_name}">
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            {error:shipping_address1}<label class="checkoutlabel" for="name-15">Address:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="shipping_address1" type="text" name="shipping_address1" value="{shipping_address1}">
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            <label class="checkoutlabel" for="name-16">Address 2:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="shipping_addres2" type="text" name="shipping_address2" value="{shipping_address2}">
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            {error:shipping_city}<label class="checkoutlabel" for="name-17">City:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="shipping_city" type="text" name="shipping_city" value="{shipping_city}">
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            <label class="checkoutlabel" for="name-23">Postcode:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="shipping_postcode" type="text" name="shipping_postcode" value="{shipping_postcode}">
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            <label class="checkoutlabel" for="field-3">State:</label>
            <select class="w-select checkoutfield" id="shipping_state" name="shipping_state" value="{shipping_state}">
              {shipping_state_options}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            {error:shipping_country}<label class="checkoutlabel" for="field-4">Country:</label>
            <select class="w-select checkoutfield" id="shipping_country" name="shipping_country">
              {shipping_country_options}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="w-clearfix">
            <label class="checkoutlabel" for="name-22">Phone:</label>
            <input class="w-input checkoutfield" id="shipping_phone" type="text" name="shipping_phone" value="{shipping_phone}">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="forminfotextblock">
      <p class="forminfotext">Shipping Method</p>
    </div>
    <div class="formblock">
      <div class="w-form">
      {shipping_methods}
          <div class="w-radio">
           <label class="w-form-label" for="shipping_method">
               <input type="radio" class="w-radio-input" name="shipping_method" value="{method_title}" id="{method_id}" />
               {method_title}
           </label>
          </div>      
      {/shipping_methods}           


         </div>
         <span id="overnightInfo" style="display:none">
          <input class="w-input overnightaccountinfo" id="field" type="text" placeholder="Enter your account number" name="field">
          <br/>
          <input class="w-input overnightaccountinfo" id="field-2" type="text" placeholder="Enter your account carrier" name="field-2" data-name="Field 2">
         </span>
         <br/>
          <input class="w-button formbutton" name="next" type="submit" value="Review Order">
      </div>
```

Comment: please provide html also its difficult to understand which field is dropdown list.

Comment: Look at jQuery's `serialize()` method. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdowns are a "select" element, not an input so jQuery isn't finding your dropdowns. You just have to change "input" to "select" for your dropdowns.

```
$("input[name='shipping_postcode']").val($("input[name='billing_postcode']").val());
$("select[name='shipping_state']").val($("select[name='billing_state']").val());
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ht3c/ (i didn't bother cleaning up the markup since the point still gets across)

Comment: When I implemented your code on my site (changing 'input' to 'select' for the drop downs in the jquery) all that happened was the shipping drop downs went blank and refused to copy any values from billing.

Comment: Never mind, your code worked great! I miss typed the code. I knew this was something simple, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" name="Copy" value="Copy Billing Address" id="billingtoshipping_checkbox"> 

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#billingtoshipping_checkbox").click(function(){
        $("[id^='shipping_']").each(function(){
            data=$(this).attr("id")
            tmpID = data.split('shipping_');
            $(this).val($("#billing_"+tmpID[1]).val())
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please note that code only answers are discouraged.